# Submit mvn Archetypes to ibiblio

Tags: maven

I have created the new archetype in mvn and I want to submit so that other users can also use this archetype.

I create the new project in mvn.

I Add `pom.xml`, `archetype.xml` and other necessary files

Then I use `mvn install` to `install` archetype.

In Documentation i need to upload the arche to `ibiblio` and i am unable to upload there can anyone tell me the steps to submit arche to mvn.

Comment: Which documentations claims so? If you like to offer it to other user Maven Central would be the best choice...

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html
Here you can see in the end of step 4

Comment: ` you can deploy (or submit it to ibiblio) it as any other artifact and the archetype will then be available to any user of Maven` 
you can tell me steps how to made templete in mvn so that it can be avalaible to other users

Comment: you can also send the update question request if you want accordingly

Comment: Ok...I think the docs needed to be updated...

Comment: I recommend to read http://central.sonatype.org/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134366/discussion-between-akash-sethi-and-khmarbaise).

Comment: Updated the documentation with correct link to Maven Central...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you read the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html), it was not up to date. Now the reference to ibiblio is removed and the documentation advises to submit to [Maven Central](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html).

> Once you are happy with the state of your archetype, you can deploy (or submit it to Maven Central) it as any other artifact and the archetype will then be available to any user of Maven.